# How can i make an application with wpf that makes an new application in runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make an application WPF C# where i can make questions and drag drop picture and then save it. And then when i hit the save button it Makes an new application. Is this impossible?  Does someone have an good url i can visit about this? I can't find anything when google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already exists such an application - it's called Visual Studio. :-)

Joking aside, to answer your question, yes, it is definitely possible to build such an application. There would be numerous ways of doing it, depending on specifics.

One aspect of such an application, let's call it AppBuilder, would be to generate and compile code for the target application. It could be done, for example, using Roslyn, the C# compiler accessible from C#.

Another aspect would be to allow the user to specify the questions, as you describe, and to allow the user to place images. Overall this would require something like a design surface with tools to manipulate the placement of the images and words, not unlike the WPF designer in Visual Studio.

While the user builds the application, there has to be a way of them to save their work, to be able to come back to it later. Does every Save generate and compile the target application? Probably not. So there is a need for a persistence mechanism, and a database, or structured file of some sort, to save the user's work in a form that can later be read back and the project reconstituted in memory.

Those are just the three most obvious features that such AppBuilder would need to support. Now for a reality check: it would not be simple, and depending on your specific requirements, it could get quite complicated. What about debugging the generated application? What about styling? Etc., etc.

I don't mean to discourage you, but maybe you can provide more information about what exactly you want to accomplish, and then we could discuss more.

Comment: Thank you, I will read more about that AppBuilder. I have thinking very much how the hell can i build an new application inside an application. My purpose is to make an small simple application where an teacher can put a question and 3 answer alt... and then drag and drop a related picture above that question. And then build it and release it. So the teacher can put it in an USB for the student/children to take home and excersice.

Comment: Then just implement a player like application that can display everything that a teacher can configure. Use some data structure (XML, Json) to save everything for later use. Just some approach i would go for. GL

Comment: So, to expand on @Benedikt Schroeder's answer, I would in this case build two applications. One "AppBuilder", which is a tool for the teacher to build the "document", and the second would be a "Player", which is meant for students to run the prepared "document". The "document" would be a structured file (could be anything really, XML, JSON, proprietary binary, SQLite database, text, or whatever you choose to store the data in).  This is definitely doable.